# JQuery Mobile Full Site Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, redirect, mobile

I'm trying to do something quite simple for a mobile site: adding a full site redirection button. My mobile site is stored in an m directory, root /m, while my redirect link goes to the directory root/index.php.

The actual button is:

```
<a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="http://www.mysite.com?m=desktop" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left">
                Full Site
</a>
```

However, the problem is that when that link is pressed, JQuery Mobile reformats everything on the index.php page and adds things like

```
<html class="ui-mobile">.
```

I can't seem to find anyone else having any issues with this for some reason.
Anyone know how to disable this for some links and enable it for others?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add rel="external" attribute into your button like this:

```
<a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="http://www.mysite.com?m=desktop" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" rel="external">
            Full Site
</a>
```

This will force open new url without loading it into current DOM structure.

Comment: Right you are. Thanks a lot!